# HTML table vertical text alignment

Tags: html, css

Currently running into trouble on a table that is a bit more complicated.

This is the result I have to achieve
[image]

The vertical alignment was done via css rotation:

```
 .vertical{
   -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   transform: rotate(-90deg);
   height:150px;
  }
```

And over here I have my current state in a codepen:
[click here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqpoJw)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
td.vertical {vertical-align: top;}
```

in your CSS

```css
th{
    background-color: #6d3550;
    padding:5px;
    border-top-left-radius:15px;
    border-top-right-radius:15px;
    color:#fff;
  }
  .vertical{
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    height:150px;

  }
  
  .dbl{
    height: 300px !important;
        
  }
td.vertical {vertical-align: top;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan=2>WELZIJN EN SOCIALE WETENSCHAPPEN</th>
  </tr>
  <!--1e graad -->
  <tr>
    <td class="vertical">
      1e graad
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="vertical" style="background-color:red;color:#fff;">
            1e en 2e jaar
          </td>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  MODERNE WETENSCHAPPEN
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  SOCIALE EN TECHNISCHE VORMING
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  (DECORATIE +) VERZORGING - VOEDING
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!--einde 1e graad-->
  
  <!--2e graad-->
    <tr>
    <td class="vertical">
      2e graad
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="vertical">
            3e en 4e jaar
          </td>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  SOCIALE EN TECHNISCHE WETENSCHAPPEN
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  VERZORGING - VOEDING
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!--einde 2e graad-->
  
  <!--3e graad-->
    <tr>
    <td class="vertical dbl">
      3e graad
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="vertical">
            5e en 6e jaar
          </td>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  SOCIALE EN TECHNISCHE WETENSCHAPPEN
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  VERZORGING
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="vertical">
            7e jaar
          </td>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  KINDERZORG
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  THUIS- EN BEJAARDENZORG/ZORGKUNDE
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!--einde 3e graad-->
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally the background-color property sets the color of a div according to the box model. Margins are always transparent. So, just increase the padding of .vertical:

```
.vertical{
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: rotate(-90deg);
height:150px;
padding:15px;
```

}

Check more about the box model [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html)